Is there any way for play an audio without user interaction?
I have a Vue Js project. I use SignalR. The data flow is continuous and I follow it on 'watch'.
watch: {
jobListAmount(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue - oldValue == 1) {
    document.getElementById("clkSoundPlay").click();
  }

<button id="clkSoundPlay" @click="onClickSoundPlay" style="display: none;"></button>

I tried click a none display button with javascript but it is not work for me.
Is there any way to do this?

This question is similar to: How to play audio?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
